# Pdf generado desde datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy usando https://datatables.net/ para armar tablas, con las mismas uso los botones para exportar datos, si bien me meti a leer la documentacion no encuentro lo siguiente y me gustaria que me comenten si es posible o no: Mi tabla tiene botones en materialize con sus simbolos correspondientes para editar y eliminar, al exportar a pdf por ejemplo me salen todos los campos inclusive los botones, es posible determinar en la creacion del boton que numero de columnas tiene que exportar Para que modificar y eliminar no salgan?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mytable').DataTable(
  {
   responsive: false,
  dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
  fixedColumns: true,
  fixedHeader: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  autoWidth: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
  info: true,
  buttons: [
    {
      extend: 'excelHtml5',
      title: 'Data export',
      className: 'btn',
      text: "Excel"
  },
  {
    extend: 'csvHtml5',
    title: 'Data export',
    className: 'btn',
    text: "Csv"
},
    {
      extend: 'pdfHtml5',
      title: 'Data export',
      className: 'btn',
      text: "Pdf"
  },
{
  extend: 'print',
  title: 'Data export',
  className: 'btn',
  text: "Imprimir"
},
 {
   extend: 'copy',
   title: 'Data export',
   className: 'btn',
   text: "Copiar"
 }
   ],
     language: {
            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                          "sFirst":    "Primero",
                          "sLast":     "Último",
                          "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                          "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                        },
            "oAria":    {
                        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                        },
            "decimal": ",",
            "thousands": "."
          }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes directamente excluir esas columnas del export de la siguiente manera:

```
{
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    title: 'Data export',
    className: 'btn',
    text: "Pdf"
    exportOptions: {
        columns: [0, 1] //exportar solo la primera y segunda columna
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Respondiendo tu comentario puedes excluir las ultimas dos columnas de tu tabla del export usando selectors:
Por ejemplo a tus últimos dos `th` de la tabla le pones como clase `class="no-exportar"`

Y luego en tu javascript usas selectors para exportar todo menos estas ultimas dos columnas de la siguiente manera:

```
{
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    title: 'Data export',
    className: 'btn',
    text: "Pdf"
    exportOptions: {
        columns: ":not(.no-exportar)" //exportar toda columna que no tenga la clase no-exportar
    }
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Excelente Leonardo, como agregado y de la forma que comentas se puede hacer que no muestre los dos ultimos? Ya que a veces exporta tablas de 4, 5 o 6 campos donde Modificar y eliminar son siempre los ultimos dos.

Comment: Añadida una edición para realizar lo que mencionas en el comentario

Comment: Sos un genio Leonardo! Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Leonardo Cabré Como podria hacer si mis columnas son dimanicas no se sabe le numero exacto que va traer

Comment: @MarcoEufragio que es lo que necesitarías hacer? podrías crear una nueva pregunta para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Tengo un problema para formular preguntas alguien le dio menos a muchas de ellas, no se si puedes verlas y veas que son buenas preguntas

Comment: @ Leonardo Cabré  Mi problema es cuando usan columns: [0, 1] , saben el numero de columnas y en mi casa la tabla no siempre va traer el mismo numero de columnas